# Parallel inheritance

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

I have objects BaseObject and DerivedObject.
Then I want to give BaseObject a BaseContainer,
and give DerivedObject a DerivedContainer.

(DerivedObject : BaseObject, DerivedContainer : BaseContainer)

For example, using the `new` keyword:

BaseObject:

> public BaseContainer Container {get; set;}

DerivedObject:

```
public new DerivedContainer Container
{ 
  get { return (DerivedContainer)base.Container; }
  set { base.Container = value;
        //Some extra things that MUST be called
      }
}
```

`virtual` and `override` won't work, because you can't change the return type (`get;` fails).
`new` doesn't work if I do `((BaseObject)myDerivedObject).Container = something`, because it's not calling the extra code (the comment part) in `DerivedObject.Container__set`.

I know I can make the property `get`-only, use `new`, and add a virtual setter method (return type is void anyways, so I can override it), but I was wondering if there was any way around this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use generics.

```
class Base<TContainer> where TContainer : Container
{
    TContainer Container { get; set; }
}

class Derived : Base<DerivedContainer> { }
```